# how to create a link for an asp.net website?

Tags: c#

I have created a website using asp.net c# for my college library,i have completed it with all their requirements.I know setup files cannot be created for asp.net websites,so,now i need a way to at least create a link for the website,so that they can access the website from anywhere in the college systems and use it.I have tried deploying and publishing nothing is working.I need any other ideas.

Comment: u mean hosting the application?

Comment: Publish the website and host it in IIS of a server to be accssible within the network

Comment: ya the depolyment succeeded but when i open the precompiled file its not opening

Comment: ya like hosting only.,within the local college server system..so that they can access from any department

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the web server you're deploying on is publicly (or at least locally within your college network) accessible. If it is, then accessing a particular website is just a matter of sharing its URL with others. You don't need a SETUP for it.

Note that what you see in a browser when you press `F5` is most likely an instance of the built-in "ASP.NET Development Server" that is accessible only on the development machine. You need to deploy your site to an instance of IIS (or some other equivalent) to access it from other machines.

Comment: thanq.and can plz tell how to create an instance of it in IIS? can u tell the exact steps? Im not so much versatile in it.

Comment: @user2605748 see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 steps that you need to perform.

1. Publish the website
2. Hosting 
       You can do it either in the IIS of local domain server to be accessible within the network 
       OR you can purchase a domain and host it on server to be accessible from anywhere.

You can see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0) on how to host application in IIS 7.

Comment: if when i did the steps given in the link am geting an error                                                           "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of deployment

1. Local
2. Global

**Local Deployment:**  Download [Cassini Web Server](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/) , Install it and Configure the WebApp or Website on that. It will give you the Network Url. Use that url to access it from anywhere in your local network.

**Global Deployment:**  Go to Domain and Hosting Provider, purchase domain and link that domain to webspace and hosting that will Support .Net framework. Generally all windows based hosting now a days have IIS. Do not go for LINUX ,as you need MONO there which is generally not available. Upload you publish pages in the root of our virtual directory. In most of the hosts its httpdocs and some where have wwwroot, depending upon the control panels. Access that pages from the domain name.

Comment: Thanq i wil try and let u know :)

Comment: the cassini web server is for non-web applications i think.,is there anyother alternative?

Comment: Cassini is specifically develoed for ASP.Net webapps/websites..The webserver that comes embedded with VS is itself a Cassini WebServer.

Answer (score 0):

this website provides all the details step by step!! its awesome it worked for me :)

http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-web-application-on-the-network-in-windows-7/